# How to completely uninstall iCloud?

Tags: macos, icloud

I know how to disable iCloud, but I want to completely remove the possibility of using the service from my Mac for security reasons. I tried to delete the related files, but I do not have permission.

So how can I make sure that no user or application or system process is able to access iCloud?

Comment: what, precisely, are you trying to delete?

Comment: iCloud is a group of Internet-based services, so your question is unclear. It's like asking "how do I delete the Internet?" Individual apps as well as system components can support many different services under the iCloud "umbrella." If you're getting stuck following directions from an article that purports to do what you want, can you post the link so we can help with that?

Comment: Are you by chance trying to delete this from a Windows computer? If so you'll need Administrative rights to do so. If you are trying to delete this from a Mac... Well you can't. You don't need to use it, but the underlying functions will still be there.

Comment: I'm voting to leave closed. Even with the edit, it's still too vague. What, specifically, have you tried so far? Are you following a guide of some sort? If so, which one?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, iCloud is built into OS X and iOS deeply and you can't just remove it completely, but you can avoid its use by disabling it.

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2613

- Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click iCloud, select "sign out".

This way iCloud will not be used on your mac and could not be used by any application.

Answer (score -3):

I already managed to delete iCloud.

Just found the way to search all files with iCloud text in his name, and deleted it.

Comment: Good news! Would you mind to share a bit more in detail which files you actually delete so that other could benefit from your work as well?