# how to turn off iCloud on a Mac

Tags: macos, icloud

Simply said: How do I turn off iCloud on my Mac?

Comment: Would help for you to specify which macOS version you're on, and which iCloud services you're talking about.

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170626/how-to-completely-uninstall-icloud?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

On my Yosemite machine there is a panel in System Preferences (click the grey apple top left corner)  On my system icloud is on the start of the 3rd row.

Click that.

You will be presented with a bunch of things that you can store in the cloud.  iCloud Drive, Photos, Mail,...

Uncheck them all.

Comment: Thank you! This was the only answer that did not assume iCloud was ubiquitous and everyone knows about 'the iCloud services' and instead was just helpful.